# Google FireBase database identify change in specific child node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am putting the **Geolocations** information in `firebase` real-time database in the following format

```
{
  "locations" : {
"1" : {
  "accuracy" : 26.48200035095215,
  "altitude" : 0,
  "bearing" : 0,
  "bearingAccuracyDegrees" : 0,
  "complete" : true,
  "elapsedRealtimeNanos" : 354390353000000,
  "fromMockProvider" : false,
  "latitude" : 18.5560446,
  "longitude" : 73.7927351,
  "provider" : "fused",
  "speed" : 0,
  "speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond" : 0,
  "time" : 1525064098554,
  "verticalAccuracyMeters" : 0
},
"2" : {
  "accuracy" : 19.844999313354492,
  "altitude" : 0,
  "bearing" : 0,
  "complete" : true,
  "elapsedRealtimeNanos" : 150409840000149,
  "fromMockProvider" : false,
  "latitude" : 18.5560117,
  "longitude" : 73.7927522,
  "provider" : "fused",
  "speed" : 0,
  "time" : 1525064076386
}
  }
}
```

> But the problem I am facing is whenever there is a change in "location" node no matter from which child whether it is from 1 or 2. I am getting notified. Because of this, I am getting wrong latitude longitude, Sometimes for "1" I am getting 2's data and for "2" I am getting 1's data

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.